# Who decide about a journals Impact Factor? What are the measurements?

Tags: journals

Dears,
I am wondering on who decides the Impact Factor of a journal? I am a writer, reader, and editor myself and consequently come across several papers. What surprises me though has to do with the inconsistency of ratings. The Ethiopian Journal of Health Development, one of the best in the country is rated low despite all the good work the journal has done over the years. I checked all the indicators and I believe the journal deserves more rating. So, I wish to hear from whoever is involved in rating journal.

Appreciate genuine and positive response

Mirgissa Kaba (PhD)

Comment: No one decides. It is calculated (see https://www.researchgate.net/post/How_is_impact_factor_calculated). Note that a huge number of senior researchers don't believe in it as a quality criterion but they use it to advertise their scientific achievements. The impact factor in 2018, for example, is computed as: (Citations in 2017 + Citations in 2016) / (Publications in 2017 + Publications in 2016). For more details, please see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Impact_factor

Comment: I am voting to close this question. The Wikipedia page has a detailed explanation: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Impact_factor

Comment: Just by hazard, are you the editor of that journal?

Comment: @Younes That's only partially true: it's calculated, but ISI decides what counts as a "citation" and what doesn't, in an arbitrary and non-verifiable process. This is described in the Wikipedia page you cited.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni ISI defines what a citation is. This is applied to all journals and does not make ISI decides about a specific journal impact factor. I think the question is about who decides that a journal A should have a higher impact and B a lower one.

Comment: Impact factor is a global measure. If, as you say, The Ethiopian Journal of Health Development is "one of the best in the country", it doesn't follow that it should be highly ranked compared to its competition worldwide.

Comment: @solar-mike "Mirgissa Kaba" is indeed listed as the [Editor-in-Chief](https://www.ajol.info/index.php/ejhd/about/contact) of the Ethiopian Journal of Health Development.

Comment: Could we please be more careful in choosing the correct reason when we vote to close a question? Surely this one has other problems, but it *is* within the scope of the site.

Answer (score 2):

The impact factor isn't necessarily a measure of usefulness or how much good a journal has done; it's calculated by a mathematical formula related to the [number of citations and articles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Impact_factor) that journal has released. No one individual or organisation decides on the impact factor of a journal.